# Is there a way to programmatically inject post actions in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to share some code between several stages, which would also need to add post actions. To do so, I thought about putting everything in a method, which will be called from

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('Some') {
            steps {
                script { commonCode() }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how could I *install* post actions in from `commonCode`. Documentation does not mention a thing. Looking at the code, implies that this DSL is basically just playing with a hash map, but I don't know would it be possible to access it from the method and modify on the fly.

Basically I would like to do something like this in `commonCode`:

```
if (something) {
    attachPostAction('always', { ... })
} else {
    attachPostAction('failure', { ... })
}
```

The only thing that works so far is that in `commonCode` I do:

```
try {
...
onSuccess()
} catch (e) {
onError()
} finally {
onAlways()
}
```

But was wondering if there is a more elegant way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I better understand the question (I hope)...

This is a pretty interesting idea--generate your post actions on the fly in previous stages.

It turns out to be really easy. I tried one option (success) that stored various closures in a list, then iterate through the list and run all the closures in the post action.  Then I did another (failure) where I just saved a single closure as a variable and ran that. Both work well.

Below is the code that does this. Uncomment the `error` line to simluate a failed build.

```
def postSuccess = []
def postFailure

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Success'){
        steps {
            script {
                println "Configure Success Post Steps"
                postSuccess[0] = {echo "This is a successful build"}
                postSuccess[1] = {
                                    echo "Running multiple steps"
                                    sh "ls -latr"
                                  }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Failure'){
        steps {
            script {
                println "Configure Failure Post Steps"
                postFailure = {
                    echo "This build failed"
                    echo "Running multiple steps for failure"
                    sh """
                        whoami
                        pwd
                    """
                }
            }
//            error "Simulate a failed build"   //uncomment this line to make the build fail
        }
    }
  } // stages

    post {
        success {
            echo "SUCCESS"
            script {
                for (def my_closure in postSuccess) {
                    my_closure()
                }
            }
        }
        failure {
            echo "FAILURE!"
            script {
                postFailure()
            }
        }
    }
} // pipeline
```

Comment: Wow, that is a pretty cool approach! Would it be possible to extend it to shared libraries as well?

Comment: Depending on how you want to do it, yes, I think that could work. You could return what you want from a library and put it into the post variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular groovy scripting outside of the `pipeline` block. While I haven't tried it, you should be able to define a method outside of there and then call it from inside the pipeline. But method calls can't be called as steps. You would need to wrap it in a script step. But `post` actions take the same steps as `steps{}` blocks, so if you can use it in`steps`, you can use it in the post sections. You will need to watch scoping carefully or you will end up trying to sort out why things are null in some places.

You can also used a shared library. You could define a step in the shared library and then use it like any other step in a `steps{}` block or one of the post blocks.

Comment: I think I might not have been clear in my question. I know I can use steps and other methods in `steps` and `post` (provided I wrap some in `script`). My question is: Can I do something in `steps` that will programatically attach new `post` actions.

Comment: Ahhhh... That is not what I had understood. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I wonder if you could use a hash or list to store some closures of things you want to run in post and then run those when you get there.  I'll see if I can mess with that later.